# Beginner: Installing PyMySQL using Anaconda (syntax error)

Tags: pip, pymysql

I am a beginner in Python and have some issues installing packages. I am using the latest version of Anaconda and try to get the "PyMySQL" package to connect to a database.

My understanding is that I would need to enter:

```
conda install pymysql
```

in a comand window (not the console). I always get the error:

> "the command conda" is not known

I also tried to use "pip list" but where would I enter it?

If anyone could help me which code to use to get packages and where to enter it, would be very grateful.

Comment: Please provide some information about the environment you're working in.

Comment: I think I understood just now how it works, was using Windows 10. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I needed to navigate in the cmd to the scripts folder in the Anaconda folder to solve my issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed the directory is "C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda3\condabin"
This did work finally, I saw some methods with path options in Windows to link this so you can use always 'conda' without navigating to this directory.